# C# DateTimePicker reference issue

Tags: c#

I have a `DateTimePicker (dtpDate)` on a windows GUI and another `DateTimePicker (trackDate)` defined behind the code.

For some reason when I use `trackDate = dtpDate;` Any changes I make to trackDate affect dtpDate as well.

Why is this happening? I don't believe it should continue to reference dtpDate.

I've tried 
`DateTimePicker trackDate` and `DateTimePicker trackDate = new DateTimeTracker();`

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: could you share more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason when I use `trackDate = dtpDate;` Any changes I make to `trackDate` affect `dtpDate` as well.

Well yes. That's because both variables now refer to the same object, because `DateTimePicker` is a class.

As a simpler example:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder y = x;
x.Append("Foo");
Console.WriteLine(y); // Prints Foo
```

It's *really* important that you understand this. It affects everything you do in C#. Read my article on [value types and reference types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more details.

If you just want to copy the *value* from one `DateTimePicker` to another, use:

```
trackDate.Value = dtpDate.Value;
```

If you're trying to do something else, you need to give us that information...